# backdrop-filter: opacity() does not seem to work

Tags: css

I am making an website on which, I am looking for an effect that I can not reproduce. I might be making it all wrong so I am going to explain the effect how I am planning on doing it but I am open for other perspectives of course.

- The effect:
  I have a background image (whole screen) I covered it with a dark grayish color. I also have a 100 by 100 pixels round div following my mouse pointer. My goal is to make this round div a kind of "window" that could see through the dark gray and so reveling the background image on mouse movement.
- My method :

1. styled the background image to be z-index: 1, height: 100vh and width: 100vw.
2. styled the background gray color to be z-index: 2, height: 100vh, width 100vw and background-color: gray;
3. styled the div following my pointer to be z-index: 3, height: 100px, width:100px, border-radius: 50% and backdrop-filter: opacity(0);

Of course I have simplified everything and I can tell the backdrop-filter is working with other options like blur or grayscale... But I don't know why the opacity options seems to do nothing at all. I have read that backdrop-filter: opacity() would require other CSS settings like mix-blend-mode. But I have tried quite a few without success.

I know I am thinking only in CSS right now, hence I am open to other suggestions with or without CSS. If you need more details do not hesitate. I am going to make an example on codeSandBox and edit my post to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Can you use Js?

Comment: Please show a code snippet

Comment: I can use JS of course,

here is a link to the sand box :
https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-bogdan-89nx8?file=/src/styles.css

I am checking your answers right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use Js this will work

```js
let image = document.querySelector('#image');
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  image.style.clipPath =
    `circle(100px at ${e.pageX}px ${e.pageY}px)`;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#background {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(24, 24, 24);
  position: fixed;
}

#image {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542831371-29b0f74f9713") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  position: fixed;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0);
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="image"></div>
```

It works basically by updating the `clip-path` property when the `mousemove` event is fired.

Edit:

I'll assume you don't know Js, so I'll add that you can play with the circle size (and even its shape) by changing this line:

`circle(100px at ${e.pageX}px ${e.pageY}px)`

to

`circle(75px at ${e.pageX}px ${e.pageY}px)`

or even this

`polygon(${e.pageX}px ${e.pageY + 25}px, ${e.pageX - 25}px ${e.pageY - 25}px, ${e.pageX + 25}px ${e.pageY - 25}px)`

Comment: I can definitely use JS, it is actually a React app. I am actually checking this way of doing things. Thank you already for this new way of seeing things.

Comment: @Othman by mistake my last edit broke the code, you actually might had not seen it working, I've fixed it if that's the case.

Comment: Thank you, your example was on point ! Made me learn about CSS mask property as well. And I even thought of doing it simply with the image and a massive  transparent div following my pointer, with a border radius of 50% and a big inset box-shadow that would let a small circle open in the middle. But in any case thank you very much, made it and learnt new things in the process.
May I ask you, how you would proceed to make a streak effect (like a shooting star) ? Kind of extending the clip-path from where it was to where it is going to, and slowly going back to shape.

Comment: I found my answer for people that would read this : I just made multiple (5, in my case) <div id='image'/> with slower transition and lower opacity.
Thanks again.

Comment: Nice to know you've learned something! In case you need help again just create another question and send me a link. I'll be happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the z-index is effective. Remember that it only applies on positioned elements, which mean that if your background-image and div do not have a "position" attribute it will not take the z-index into consideration.

Comment: the z-index and everything works since I can make backdrop-filter works other opacity. my issue seems to be around backdrop-filter: opacity(), there might be something that I am missing.